# Is there a script for obtaining the low watermark offsets of a topic in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Apache Kafka provides a script, [kafka-consumer-groups.sh](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_lag), to inspect the offsets of a topic. This script outputs the current offsets (committed offsets) and the log-end offsets (high watermark offsets) of the partitions of a topic.

I would like to ask if there is a script to obtain the low watermark offsets (earliest offsets) for a topic? As I understand, the low watermark offset is commonly 0, but it can be other values if messages are deleted from the topic due to the configured retention policy (for example, [retention.ms](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#topicconfigs_retention.ms)).

Answer (score 2):

We are using the [kcat](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat) command line client to achieve this:

```
kcat -b $BROKER -Q -t $TOPIC:$PARTITION:-1 # high watermark
kcat -b $BROKER -Q -t $TOPIC:$PARTITION:-2 # low watermark
```

That is not a script to run on the Kafka broker itself, but maybe it helps people anyway. The key idea is to put -1 or -2 as the timestamp to the `-Q` command.